# Which endpointscfg.py to use?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am currently using google-cloud-sdk and it contains three endpointscfg.py

1. google-cloud-sdk/bin/endpointscfg.py
2. google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py
3. google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py

which version I should use to generate open api spec?

**Using the first one gives an error:**
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py: error: argument {get_client_lib, get_discovery_doc}: invalid choice: 'get_openapi_spec' (choose from 'get_client_lib', 'get_discovery_doc')

**Using second gives error:**
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py: error: argument {get_client_lib, get_discovery_doc}: invalid choice: 'get_openapi_spec' (choose from 'get_client_lib', 'get_discovery_doc')

**Using third one gives error:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 65, in 
    from endpoints import api_config
ImportError: No module named endpoints

I am trying to follow

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#endpoints_configure

to generate open api spec for my own api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the one included in the new google-endpoints package. If you follow the instructions in that tutorial, it would be `lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py` where `lib` is inside your app directory.